# Как починить кодировки в Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, кодировка, utf-8

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Русский текст выводит непонятными символами, хотя раньше все исправно работало. Visual Studio даже было переустановлено, проблема не решилась. Что можно сделать??